# View as FF 3.6 in FF 7 - Possible?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, cross-browser

in IE you can view pages as previous rendering engine. You use 9 and view as 8,7,6.

If this possible in Firefox? I'm using FF7 and I want to see how a website displays in say 3.6.

Is this possible or am I going to need multiple versions installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "No, you're going to have to install multiple versions."

FF doesn't have a compatiblity view like IE does. (If the example of IE is anything to go by, this is probably a good thing)

Firefox can have multiple versions installed on the same machine without too much trouble, but if you want to make things even easier, you might want to try the [Utilu collection](http://utilu.com/UtiluMFC/) which is an installer that can install multiple FF versions on your machine at once.

Comment: "If the example of IE is anything to go by, this is probably a good thing" — Indeed, compatibility mode is designed to "get most sites working" and not to "provide a simulator for developers" and it shows.